# Android conflict between Kotlin Int and Java int representation

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas

I have colors stored as `IntArray`s this is a simple function to convert to the argb color value used by Android.

```kotlin
fun IntArray.toColor(): UInt {
    var color: Long = 0xFF000000
    val maxIndex = size - 1
    this.withIndex().forEach { (index, value) ->
        color = color or (value.toLong() shl (8 * (maxIndex - index)))
    }
    return color.toUInt()
}
```

If you look at Android's own source code, you'll find color notation expressed as below

```java
...
@ColorInt public static final int RED         = 0xFFFF0000;
@ColorInt public static final int GREEN       = 0xFF00FF00;
@ColorInt public static final int BLUE        = 0xFF0000FF;
...
```

If I try to use the same value e.g. `0xFFFF0000` as Kotlin `Int` it's not possible, says the literal doesn't conform to the type `Int`. So I use `UInt` in my method.
Android's own code(in Java) `android.graphics.Paint.setColor(@ColorInt int color)` requires `int` and in my Kotlin Code I can only use and `Int` and not a `UInt` and when I use `UInt.toInt()` the value gets messed up.

Example

```kotlin
val color  = arrayOf(0x11, 0x22, 0x33).toIntArray().toColor()
print(color.toString(16)) // ff112233 (UInt)
print(color.toInt().toString(16)) // -eeddcd (Int)
```

How do I convert any Kotlin type larger then `Int` to `Int` with the value intact?

Is it possible to solve this without calling Java in Kotlin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin `Int` should work well. Have you tried to use this value as color? Nevermind that `color.toInt().toString(16)` returns `-eeddcd`. It should return that because `Int` value dedicates highest bit for sign. That's representation issue, but the actual value is `0xff112233`. So Kotlin `Int` with value `-eeddcd` when you pass it to `setColor` should look same as `0xff112233`.

So try implement your function `Int.toColor` as follows:

```
fun IntArray.toColor(): Int {
    var color: Int = 0xFF000000.toInt()
    val maxIndex = size - 1
    this.withIndex().forEach { (index, value) ->
        color = color or (value shl (8 * (maxIndex - index)))
    }
    return color
}
```

Comment: You're right, it's the representation conflict between Java and Kotlin. The issue in the language is that Kotlin has UInt, but when calling Java code where we have to pass the value as Java int, it only accepts Kotlin Int, while logically it should accept both Int and UInt.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the colors in working code. It's working fine, the issue is in Kotlin's string representation.